# don't print empty fields in PHP

Tags: php

Okay so I have this small database containing columns named "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" and "tag4". Now, I display those tags along with the corresponding portfolio item, but not every portfolio item has 4 tags, meaning sometimes some of these tag fields can be empty.

Now I'm printing all my portfolio items in an if loop, so for every item I print all the 4 tags meaning that if some tag fields are empty, I also receive empty spaces (e.g. in my list the bullets show up but obivously no text).

So basically what I want to do, is ONLY print the tag if it is not empty. But I don't understand how to do this with multiple tags?

This is my code:

```
print(" 

    <ul class=\"tagList\">
          <li>{$row['tag1']}</li>
          <li>{$row['tag2']}</li>
          <li>{$row['tag3']}</li>
          <li>{$row['tag4']}</li>
    </ul>

 ");
```

Comment: `array_filter($row);` will remove empty elements http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php see example #2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the variable is empty before printing it:

```
print("<ul class=\"tagList\">");

if($row['tag1']) {
    print("<li>{$row['tag1']}</li>");
}

if($row['tag2']) {
    print("<li>{$row['tag2']}</li>");
}
```

etc.

You can make it easier for yourself by using a for loop:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    if($row['tag'.$i]) {
        print("<li>{$row['tag'.$i]}</li>");
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to use `empty` here.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO if a variable is empty the if statement will not be true.

Comment: You're right. Though, your loop needs to go through `$i <= 5;`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO In the question there are four `<li>` elements, so `$i < 5` will loop 4 times. Also `$i <= 4` will, but not `$i <= 5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP's empty comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check if the value is empty.  If it's not empty, [print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) the value, otherwise, [print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) nothing.

For something this small, you could even encapsulate your `<li>` elements in the empty comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This will dump the whole of $row. IF this is what you want.

```
$row=array_filter($row); // see below
if(sizeof($row)>0)
{
    echo '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>', $row).'</li></ul>';
}
```

NOTE: array_filter will remove elements with the values: false, null and 0

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_filter($row,'strlen'); to remove all empty elements and then loop through $row printing each tag.

However, I would guess that $row contains more then just tag1, tag2, tag3, and tag4. So you could try this instead.

```
    print "<ul class=\"tagList\">";
    for($i=1;$i<5;$i++) {
            if(strlen($row['tag'.$i])>0) {
                    print "<li>{$row['tag'.$i]}</li>";
            }
     }
     print "</ul>";
```